# jquery treeview in grails

Tags: jquery, grails, groovy, treeview

I am trying to implement the [async jQuery treeview](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/async.html) in my grails project.. So my requirement is that on loading of the page i want to provide following structure :

```
-> Overview
-> Resources
  --> User Activity
  --> Network Sources
```

And by clicking on **User Activitity/Network Sources** it should have following children :

```
--> User Activity
  ---> By Day of Week
  ---> By Time of Day
  .....
--> Network Resources
  ---> By Day of Week
  ---> By Time of Day
  .....
```

Now the children list of Resources should be coming from controller, so based on that I have tried with following piece of code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initTrees() {
                jQuery("#mixed").treeview({
                        url: "/.../.../getSubTreedata"
                })

        }
 $(document).ready(function(){
                initTrees();
        });
</script>

<ul id="mixed">
        <li><span>Overview</span></li>
        <li id="36" class="hasChildren">
            <span>Resources</span>
            <ul>
                       <li><span class="placeholder">&nbsp;</span></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

And controller has following piece of code :

```
def getSubTreedata = {
        def jsonChild1 = [text:"By Day of Week"];
        def jsonChild2 = [text:"By Time of Day"];
        def jsonChild3 = [text:"Holiday"];
        def jsonChild4 = [text:"Weekend"];
        def jsonChild5 = [text:"Time Windows"];
        def jsonResult = [
            text: "User Activity",
            expanded : false,
            classes : "important",
            children : [jsonChild1,jsonChild2,jsonChild3,jsonChild4,jsonChild5],
        ]
        
        def convertedData = jsonResult as JSON
        convertedData = new StringBuffer(convertedData.toString()).insert(0, "[");
        convertedData = new StringBuffer(convertedData.toString()).insert(convertedData.length(), "]");
        println "convertedData = "+convertedData;
        render convertedData;
```

Ultimately its printing
`convertedData = convertedData = [{"text":"User Activity","expanded":false,"classes":"important","children":[{"text":"By Day of Week"},{"text":"By Time of Day"},{"text":"Holiday"},{"text":"Weekend"},{"text":"Time Windows"}]}]`

But it's not matching with my requirement, i need to create an array at controller and parse it into JSON and return it...

Any help would be highly Appreciated...

**: UPDATE :**
Now I am able to show the proper tree format at UI, but my major question is how can I show all the children i.e. "By day of week", "Time of Day" etc as a link with Ajax.Updater... I know I need to change jquery.treeview.async.js file which actually is displaying all the childs.... But I am not getting how can I create them as a link and call Ajax.Updater by clicking on that link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Resolved it by overriding jquery.treeview.async.js... In this file I have modified createNode function, by default it was adding span tag, instead of that i have made it a hyperlink....

Now the code looks like :

```
function createNode(parent) {
            var current;

            if(this.id && this.owner && this.menu){
              if(this.menu=='users'){
                        current = $("<li/>").attr("id", this.id || "").html("<a class="+this.classes+" href=\"showDetails/\" onclick=\"jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:'employeeId="+this.id+"&resourceSel=All', url:'/Project/users/showDetails/',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#behaviorDiv').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});return false;\">"+this.text+"</a>").appendTo(parent);
                else{
                       current = $("<li/>").attr("id", this.id || "").html("<a class="+this.classes+" href=\"showActivityDetails/\" onclick=\"jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',data:'resourceName="+this.id+"&resourceSel=All', url:'/Project/resource/showActivityDetails/',success:function(data,textStatus){jQuery('#behaviorDiv').html(data);},error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}});return false;\">"+this.text+"</a>").appendTo(parent);
                }
```

And my gsp has following code :

function initTrees() {

                jQuery("#peerTreeView").treeview({
                        url: "/Project/peer/getSubTreeData",
                        ajax: {
                data: {
                                  "peerName":'${peerName}'
                                },
                                type:"post"
                         }
                })
        }
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                initTrees();
        });





  
    
      
        
          
            
              
                
                  
                    Resources

- 

${g.message(code:'users.behavior.contentLabel')}

```
            }
```

And inside the controller getSubTreeData action has following piece of code :

```
    def getSubTreeData = {
        def data = [
            [ text:'Peer Activity',
                id : params.peerName,
                owner : 'Resources',
                expanded: false,
                classes:  'icon-userActivity',
                menu : 'peer',
                children: [
                    [ text: "By Day of Week", classes:'icon-date', id:params.peerName, menu : 'peer', owner:'peerActivity'],
                    [ text: "By Time of Day", classes:'icon-time', id:params.peerName, menu : 'peer', owner:'peerActivity'],
                    [ text: "Holiday",        classes:'icon-date', id:params.peerName, menu : 'peer', owner:'peerActivity'],
                    [ text: "Weekend",        classes:'icon-date', id:params.peerName, menu : 'peer', owner:'peerActivity'],
                    [ text: "Daily",   classes:'icon-date', id:params.peerName, menu : 'peer', owner:'peerActivity'],
                    [ text: "Weekly",   classes:'icon-date', id:params.peerName, menu : 'peer', owner:'peerActivity'],
                    [ text: "Monthly",   classes:'icon-date', id:params.peerName, menu : 'peer', owner:'peerActivity']

                ]
            ],
            [
                text:'Network Sources',
                id : params.peerName,
                owner : 'Resources',
                expanded: false,
                classes:  'icon-networkSources',
                menu : 'peer',
                children: [
                    [ text: "By Day of Week", classes:'icon-date', id:params.peerName,  menu : 'peer', owner:'networkSources'],
                    [ text: "By Time of Day", classes:'icon-time', id:params.peerName,  menu : 'peer', owner:'networkSources'],
                    [ text: "Holiday",        classes:'icon-date', id:params.peerName,  menu : 'peer', owner:'networkSources'],
                    [ text: "Weekend",        classes:'icon-date', id:params.peerName,  menu : 'peer', owner:'networkSources'],
                    [ text: "Daily",   classes:'icon-date', id:params.peerName, menu : 'peer', owner:'networkSources'],
                    [ text: "Weekly",   classes:'icon-date', id:params.peerName, menu : 'peer', owner:'networkSources'],
                    [ text: "Monthly",   classes:'icon-date', id:params.peerName, menu : 'peer', owner:'networkSources']
                ]
            ]
        ]
        render data as JSON
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this work?

```
def getSubTreedata = {
  def data = [ 
    [ text:     'User Activity', 
      expanded: 'false',
      classes:  'important',
      children: [
        [ text: "By Day of Week" ],
        [ text: "By Time of Day" ],
        [ text: "Holiday" ],
        [ text: "Weekend" ],
        [ text: "Time Windows" ],
      ]
    ]
  ]
  render data as JSON
}
```

ie: wrap it all in an array, and just render that as JSON

**Edit:**

To let some of the children be clickable, looks like you need to do:

```
def getSubTreedata = {
  def data
  switch( param.root ) {
    case '1': // Day of week id
      data = [ [ text: 'Days of the week go in here' ] ]
      break
    case '2': // Time of day id
      data = [ [ text: 'Time of the day goes in here' ] ]
      break
    default: // No recognisable param.root, so render the root tree
      data = [ 
        [ text:     'User Activity', 
          expanded: 'false',
          classes:  'important',
          children: [
            [ text: "By Day of Week", id:'1', hasChildren:'true' ],
            [ text: "By Time of Day", id:'2', hasChildren:'true' ],
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  }
  render data as JSON
}
```

Then, this method should get a `param.root` value when it is called so you can tell which node was expanded

Comment: @tim thanks alot for the quick response.. now it's displaying as per my requirement... But my major concern is that how can I display all the children as a link instead of the simple span appearing right now...?

Comment: Not sure, but at a guess...what happens if you put `expanded:'false'` in the children map elements?

Comment: @Nirmal ahhh...  Jut used firebug on that demo page...  Edited my answer to show how to do this...

Comment: @tim What if I want to create the link "By Days of Week" and call Ajax.Updater on that link ? I guess I need to modify jquery.treeview.async.js file...

Comment: Not sure I get you...  does that last example not work?  I can't test it here, so it was just a guess.  Doesn't that create a tree with 2 nodes, and when those nodes are clicked, they get a child node rendered for each (by another call to the server)?

Comment: its creating tree with 2 nodes, and when those nodes are clicked its rendering the data and printing just under those child nodes... Instead of that I want to call some another action of different controller and render the template at right side of tree....

Comment: Right...  I have no idea...  Why not just get this method to call a  Grails Service which performs the map generation depending on the parent node?  As for the layout, can't you just pass a CSS style in `classes`?  But without being there, it's going to be hard to advise any further than that...  Sorry